# Problems passing integer and serializable on bundle

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a serializable and an Integer or a String but on my child activity I only get the serializable

Parent Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Class1.this, Class2.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key", 23);
bundle.putSerializable(serializable, object);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Child Activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int intKey;
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
object = (Object) bundle.getSerializable(serializable);
intKey = bundle.getInt("key", 0);
```

I get the serializable object but I can't get the integer aswell

Comment: it seems good but try to use bundle.getInt("key") instead of bundle.getInt("key", 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and put the int directly on Intent and not through bundle.
Meaning :

```
intent.putExtra("key", 23);
```

And get it with :

```
intent.getIntExtra("key", 23);
```

Should work

But if you have a reason you wanna use the bundle you can try what Sajmon said in the comment, and `bundle.getInt("key")` i read somewhere that it's not the same, i'm not sure why.